# MySQL SELECT distinct very slow

Tags: php, mysql

For my mobile App i am using a web service to get the images and all records from the MySQL database, its like Instagram.

But SELECT DISTINCT taking more than 7 - 8 seconds.is there any thing that i can do for reduce the time?

```
SELECT distinct count(*) as totalrecord ,p.description,p.photo_id ,p.user_id,p.imagepath1 ,p.friends, p.is_report_photo,
    p.imagepath2,p.imagepath3,p.imagepath4,p.imagepath5,p.count_comment,p.count_like,p.created as photo_created ,

    (select username from users where id = p.user_id) as username , 
    (select country from users where id = p.user_id) as country, 
    (select email from users where id = p.user_id) as email , 
    (select image_path from users where id = p.user_id) as image_path ,
    (select gender from users where id = p.user_id) as gender, 
    (select privacy from users where id = p.user_id) as privacy,
    (select audio_privacy from users where id = p.user_id) as audio_privacy,
    (select video_privacy from users where id = p.user_id) as video_privacy,
    (select photo_privacy from users where id = p.user_id) as photo_privacy,

    If(pl.user_id && pl.photo_id !='',like_status,0) as islike ,
    If(pr.user_id && pr.photo_id !='',1,0) as isreport,
    p.user_visibility

    from friends as fr
    inner join users as u on u.id = (select distinct if (fr.user_id != $user_id,fr.user_id,(fr.to_user_id)) as rd
    from friends) && fr.read_status = '1'
    inner join photos as p on (p.user_visibility = 'p')
    LEFT JOIN photolike as pl ON pl.photo_id = p.photo_id && pl.user_id = $user_id
    LEFT JOIN photo_report as pr on pl. photo_id = pr.photo_id && pr.user_id = $user_id     
    ORDER BY p.photo_id DESC;
```

Comment: you make subQuery in each fields and records..?

Comment: i suggest to rewrite your query using joins instead, not subQuery in each fields.. if use subQuery, your query will execute these subquery in each fetching record. and it will make more slowly.

Comment: Yeah sure i already started it. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [mysql indexing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html) that will reduce the time

Answer (score 1):

```
Try using group-by clause instead of distinct.
```